# If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not independent random variables, then $f(\alpha,\beta)=0$.

Tags: probability-theory, independence

In page 45 from the book *Numerical Methods for Stochastic Computations*, by Dongbin Xiu, it is stated that, since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not independent random variables, then there exists a function $f$ such that $f(\alpha,\beta)=0$. Furthermore, it says that, equivalently, the dependence between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ implies that there exists a function $g$ such that $\beta=g(\alpha)$. Why does non-independence imply the existence of $f$ and/or $g$ ?

Edit: Dependent means not independent. The function $f$ is nonzero.

Comment: The existence of $g$ is wrong, if by *dependent* you understand *not independent*. The existence of $f$ doesn't require any hypotheses, take $f=0$.

Comment: Are there any assumptions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ beyond what you have stated?

Comment: Trivially, if $\alpha$ is a random variable that takes on 3 values and $\beta$ is a random variable which takes on 2 (easy enough to generate such examples which fail to be independent) then $\alpha$ can't be a function of $\beta$.

Comment: @JohnColeman Literally, the book says: "If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not independent of each other, it implies that there exists a function $f$ such that $f(\alpha,\beta)=0$. Then it is possible to find a random variable $Z(\omega)$  to parameterize the relation such that $\alpha(\omega)=a(Z(\omega))$, $\beta(\omega)=b(Z(\omega))$ and $f(a,b)=0$. Or, equivalently, the dependence between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ implies that there exists a function $g$ such that $\beta=g(\alpha)$."

Comment: I don't know what they are driving at, but the existence of $g$ based simply on dependence is trivially false. A continuous example: pick a point on the unit disk with uniform probability and let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the x and y coordinates of the chosen point. Clearly dependent, and just as clearly neither is a function of the other.

Comment: Again, that's assuming that by *dependent* you mean "not independent". Maybe the book assumes that *dependent* means by definition that such a $g$ exists...?

Comment: What are $\alpha$ and $\beta$? I suspect that the author isn't talking about random variables in general but is instead talking about random variables which arise in a given context. It is unlikely that they would make such a trivial blunder. It is more likely that this passage has a context, one which you haven't given.

Comment: @JohnColeman I see that the existence of $g$ is false: $\Omega=\{\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3\}$, $P(\{\omega_i\})=1/3$, $i=1,2,3$, $\alpha(\omega_i)=i$, $\beta(\omega_1)=1$ and $\beta(\omega_2)=\beta(\omega_3)=2$. Since $P(\alpha=2,\beta=2)=1/3\neq 2/9=P(\alpha=2)P(\beta=2)$, then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are dependent. But it is not possible that $\alpha=g(\beta)$, otherwhise $g(2)=2$ and $g(2)=3$. However, $f$ does exist, as one can take any nonzero function with $f(1,1)=0$, $f(2,2)=0$ and $f(3,2)=0$. Is the existence of $f$ false?

Comment: @JohnColeman $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are random variables in an ODE: $du/dt(t,\omega)=-\alpha(\omega)u$, $u(0,\omega)=\beta(\omega)$.

Comment: My second example shows that the existence of $f$ is also false. Only a function which is zero on the entire disk vanishes on the entire disk.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a context: https://books.google.ie/books?id=GY9qyJd4CvQC&pg=PA44&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @JohnColeman There is no more information than $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be random inputs in an ODE.

Comment: I am puzzled. The author probably had a certain type of application in mind (such as random but time-dependent inputs) but failed to communicate the needed assumptions.

Comment: This was already asked on the site (with the same conclusion that the book is wrong) but I cannot find the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without additional assumptions, neither the existence of a nonzero function $f$ nor the function $g$ follows.

For a simple example, pick a point on the unit disk with uniform probability and let α and β be the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the chosen point. Clearly dependent, and just as clearly neither is a function of the other. Furthermore, the only way for $f(\alpha,\beta)$ to be zero is for it to vanish uniformly.